# Getting ValueError while writing an if-else loop to populate a data frame column based on a condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas data frame which has a column `'daysofweek'`. I am trying to write a simple if-else block to populate a new column `'weekend'` as 1 if daysofweek is 5 or 6. And, 0 otherwise. I am getting this error: `"ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."`

I tried changing 'or' to '|' but the error persists.

```
if train['day of week'] == 5 | train['day of week'] == 6:
    train['weekend'] = 1
else:
    train['weekend'] = 0
```

I expect the `'weekend'` column to be populated with 0's and 1's but it is giving the error.

Comment: `train['day of week']` will give you all the values of the column (a pandas.Series object), not only one value. so your if-statement is something like `if [v1,v2,v3,v4...] == 5` which is an error since you cannot compare the truth value of a list with a single number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution should be simplify with converting boolean mask to integers:

```
train['weekend'] = (train['day of week'] >= 5).astype(int)
```

Or create mask by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
train['weekend'] = train['day of week'].isin([5,6]).astype(int)
```

Or using [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
train['weekend'] = np.where(train['day of week'] >= 5, 1, 0)
```